# How can I stop RSelenium browser from closing automatically when left idle?

Tags: r, rselenium

I use RSelenium to run a scraping loop which sometimes (infrequently) meets an error and then stops.

The problem for me is that when this happens and I don't check in on the RSelenium session for a while (for like half an hour or so..?), the RSelenium session closes automatically, which removes logs from the session that I want to check.

How can I stop this from happening -- or more precisely, how can I prevent the RSelenium session (and the Firefox browser opened from RSelenium) from closing when left idle for an extended time period?

The following is how I start the scraping -- I open the Firefox browser like this, then go to the URL that I want and then start scraping.

```
library(RSelenium)
# Running with the browser open ------------------------------------------------
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(port = 4454L, browser = "firefox")

remDr <- rD$client
remDr$open()
```

P.S. Just to clarify, it's okay that the scraping stops once in a while -- that's how I can check for loopholes that I am missing. What I need is a way for me to stop the RSelenium session from closing when left idle. Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar issue, https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/241

```
chrome_prefs = 
  list(  
   # chrome prefs
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
    "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE
    )

chrome_args = 
  c(
  # chrome command arguments
    '--headless',
    '--window-size=1200,1800',
    '-sessionTimeout 57868143'
    )

eCaps_notimeout = 
  list(chromeOptions = 
         list(
           prefs = chrome_prefs,
           args = chrome_args 
  ))


  remDr <- remoteDriver(
    browserName = "chrome",
    extraCapabilities = eCaps_withhead
  )
```

Further reference [Is there a way too prevent selenium automatically terminating idle sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438913/is-there-a-way-too-prevent-selenium-automatically-terminating-idle-sessions)