# How to remove Selenium Grid Node from grid if 'Failed to Connect'?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using AWS EC2 instances to create a Selenium Grid. I have one instance acting as the Hub and other instances acting as nodes.

Once I terminate the nodes, they still remain in the grid for quite sometime (like 15-20 minutes) before being completely removed, therefore, the API is returning incorrect values:

[image: GRID]

For example, the API is returning:

```
"slotCounts": {
    "free": 9,
    "total": 10
  },
```

But really, there are ONLY 4 slots total, because the other nodes are no longer connected. Is there a configuration setting that will remove the nodes from grid faster after there is no longer a connection?

I start the Hub like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -port 4444;
```

And the clients like this:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.1.119:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2,version=latest,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver
```

The nodes do eventually disappear from the grid but only after they have been quit (by quit, I mean after the computer that runs the node has been shutdown) for quite awhile (maybe 10-20 mins).

I looked at this Stack Overflow question: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395659/properties-for-selenium-grid-hub-node-config)

And I can't figure out if I need to set `nodePolling`, `timeout`, `browsertimout` or a combination of them?

**Update:**
I just tested it again, and after the computer that runs the nodes was shutdown, it took around 20-22 mins for the grid to reflect that in the API.

Comment: You Hub and Grid starting commands?

Comment: I updated my Question with that info

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59648301/7429447) helptext:

```
-timeout, -sessionTimeout
  <Integer> in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server
  automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X
  seconds. The test slot will then be released for another test to use.
  This is typically used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node
  roles, cleanUpCycle must also be set. If a node does not specify it, the
  hub value will be used.
```

So once the nodes are terminated to remove them completely from the [console](http://localhost:4444/grid/console) you can configure either of the following parameters:

- *`-timeout`*

  ```
  java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.225.173:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2 -timeout 2
  ```
- *`-sessionTimeout`*:

  ```
  java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.225.173:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2 -sessionTimeout 3
  ```
- *`cleanUpCycle`*:

  ```
  java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.225.173:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2 -cleanUpCycle 4
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Is there a way too prevent selenium automatically terminating idle sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496296/7429447)

Comment: So using ANY 1 out of those params (timeout, sessionTimeout, cleanUpCycle) will accomplish what I need? I re-read the documentation so many times and couldn’t make sense of my exact need. I thought the param I need to set would be on the hub though, not the nodes?

Comment: @mcool Even that would be a better approach as the help text explicitly specifies _`...If a node does not specify it, the hub value will be used....`_

Comment: Okay I will try it out on the nodes first when I get back to my computer

Comment: So I tried as you suggested with setting the `timeout` param to `2` for the node and it did not do as expected. I thought that this would remove the node from the console after `2` seconds. I terminated the instance, and as of right now it has been `7` mins and it is still in the console.

Comment: @mcool Observe the HUB logs. The browser state (cookies) needs additional time to expire.

Comment: And how do I fix it so that the node gets removed from console immediately? That's what my original question was

Comment: Check the reference discussion

Comment: The link you put at the bottom of your answer? That also does not help, that is just reiterating what you have already said that did not work